# Android: I am unable to import a project into my workspace

Tags: android

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

I'm trying to include that library/project into my workspace, however nothing shows up when I choose the folder to import. I have no clue what I'm doing wrong as I use the same method to import other sample projects. There must be something different about this project.

Could someone try it out?

Comment: Make sure you are trying to import the library folder and not the entire folder itself. It looks like the library is the android project you can import.

Comment: What if you do 'Create New Project from existing source' instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. File->New-> Android Project
2. select Create project from existing source
3. Browse...->JakeWharton-Android-ViewPagerIndicator\library
4. Finish

if any errors in project exist,try next:

1. go to libs folder in eclipse Package Explorer
2. right click on android-support-v4.jar
3. Build Path -> Add to build path

Comment: I keep getting AndroidManifest is missing, even though it's in the folder. There is no libs folder for this project?

Comment: I ended up placing the "library" folder on its own, and renamed it to ViewIndicator, which is the same as the project I created.

Comment: I am trying to use the viewpagerindicator but not able as i am not getting how to do it... can you or someone please help me in step by step.. thanx